# How do I print a certain variable from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm sorry if I used the wrong term, but I am only trying to print the name of a student from an ArrayList. The name can be found in quotes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Student {
private String name;
private int idNum;

public Student(String string, int i) {
    name = string;
    idNum = i;
}
public String getName()
{return name;}
public int getNum()
{return idNum;}
public String toString()
{return name+" "+idNum;}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> classroom = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student s1 = new Student("Eugene", 2596);
    classroom.add(0, s1); 
    Student s2 = new Student("Bob", 1111);
    classroom.add(1, s2);
    Student s3 = new Student("Gary", 7993);
    classroom.add(2, s3);
    Student s4 = new Student("Dan", 6689);
    classroom.add(3, s4);
    Student s5 = new Student("Joe Kid", 3592);
    classroom.set(2, s5);
    Student s6 = new Student("Sue Kim", 8541);
    classroom.set(3, s6);
    classroom.remove(0);
    Student s7 = new Student("Bob Lee", 6317);
    classroom.add(s7);
    classroom.remove(4);
    System.out.println(classroom.toString());
    for(int i=0; i<classroom.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(classroom.**getName**(i));
    }
}

}
```

There was an error at the end with getName(I put it in asterisks), and I'm not sure how to fix it. Thank you if you can find out how to fix it.

Comment: `classroom.get(i).getName()` - You need to get the object from the `ArrayList` first, then you can access it's properties

Comment: Nit: `System.out.println(classroom.toString());` can be written as `System.out.println(classroom);`: the method will automatically call the `toString()` method for you (as well as handling the null case). You can also just write `classroom.add(new Student("Eugene", 2596));`, which means you don't have to keep making up new variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
System.out.println(classroom.get(i).getName());
```

You need to access the `Student` object first using `classroom.get(i)`, then access his `name`.

Small **P.S**: if you're using **Java 8**, you can do this:

```
classroom.stream()
         .forEach(student -> System.out.println(student.getName()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
for (Student student: classroom) {
    System.out.println(student.getName());
}
```